# Python: objects in a list

Tags: python, scripting

How do I make it so that the circles in this list can be modified or removed later on? Isn't the list different from the actual objects?

```
def drawAllBubbles(window,numOfBubbles):
    bublist=list()
    for x in range(numOfBubbles):
        p1= random.randrange(1000)
        p2= random.randrange(1000)
        center= graphics.Point(p1,p2)
        bubx = center.getX()
        buby = center.getY()
        r = random.randint(1, 255)#randomize rgb values
        g = random.randint(1, 255)
        b = random.randint(1, 255)
        circle = graphics.Circle(center, 5)
        circle.setFill(color_rgb(r, g, b))
        circle.setOutline("black")
        circle.draw(window)
        bublist.append(circle)
    return bublist
    window.getMouse()
```

This part of the script essentially draws

[image]

And then returns a list of circles.

Comment: ```bublist``` contains the circles.  They **can** be retrieved, used, modified, removed...

Comment: @wwii Would I be able to run "getX()" and "getY()" for each circle in the list?

Comment: If ```Circle```s have those methods, then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects are contained in `bublist`

If you iterate over the list, you can change, remove, or redraw the circles. For example:

```
for bubble in bublist:
    bubble.setOutline("green")
    bubble.draw(window)
```

Comment: `for bubble in bublist:`  
       `a= bubble.getCenter()`  
      ` b = a.getX()`  
       `c = a.getY()`  
        `print(a)` For some reason, I can't get this to print.

Comment: @aero26 That line of code will try to print `a`, which refers to the `Point` object returned by `bubble.getCenter()`. I assume you're trying to print the coordinates, in which case you should try `print((b, c))`. In Python 2.x: `print (b, c)`